# PivotItem's border brush not setting in my UWP app

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

PivotItem's border brush not setting in my UWP app. Below is my xaml code. Please help..

```
<Pivot x:Name="DocTab" Title="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="980"  Margin="0,50" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" >
    <PivotItem Header="Document 1" Margin="40,30"  >
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="Document 2"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="940">
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

Comment: If you want to set the border in the PivotItem then place your BorderBrush and BorderThickness in PivotItem not Pivot

Comment: Can you precise what you are trying to achieve? The code you use ahould set the border of the whole pivot, not its items.

Comment: Yes I tried doing both. I applied border brush to pivot first and then to pivot item then to both but nothing works

Comment: Also try adding a grid with height and width within the PivotItem

Comment: AbsoluteSith...thanks the grid border worked :)